# What is the Grails Artefact Evaluation Order and Context?

Tags: grails

In particular, I'm interested in the grails-app/conf set of artifacts: BootStrap, Config, DataSource, *Filters, etc.  The order is important and so is the "context", and by that I don't necessarily mean in the Spring sense, but the set of variables/symbols available, side-effects, and any other info that might affect symbol resolution.

Ideally, someone can point me at the underlying Grails code that drives this process s.t. I can best understand both control flow and symbol resolution.

Comment: In Grails 2.3.4 ConfigurationHelper loads DataSource before merging external config.